# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, nativescript

After installing `nativescript-plugin-firebase` I can't build my app anynore with `tns build android`.
I get this error:

```
nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'nativescript_plugin_firebase'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.jar
     Required by:
         project :
```

Here is my `platforms/android/build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

[Here](https://termbin.com/viee) is `platforms/android/app/build.gradle`:

[Here](https://termbin.com/o1s4) is `platforms/tempPlugin/nativescript_plugin_firebase/build.gradle`

Comment: i think there is a mismatch in gradle build and tool versions

Comment: @JawadMalik how can I fix it?

Comment: show app level build.gradle

Comment: share your build.gradle module app file also

Comment: @JawadMalik Where is build.gradle module app file?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't any network problem? 
Restrictions in your network always create such issues too. I had this problem in my office network.

Comment: @IndranilDutta It could be that since I'm in a restricted network but I can use tor.

Comment: @IndranilDutta I also tried tns proxy with tor but it's having the same issue.

Comment: @IndranilDutta I ran it again with tor. this time it is looking better. ifstat shows some download is going on. tns is kinda stuck at the part where it was supposed to give error, I guess it's downloading some stuff. I'll let you know here.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay I just changed my project build tool to 3.4.2 from 3.4.1 and it worked fine in the open network I'm using. I'm sure it's a network restriction at your end. I hope any open network e.g. mobile hotspot, dongle, etc. would work for you.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay Great to hear that your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You probably have another plugin depending on Google Play Services
>   (Google Maps, perhaps). We need to pin to a specific play services
>   version to play nice with others, so open
>   **`app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle`** and add:

**Example**

```
android {   
            project.ext {
            googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.0"   //"16.0.+
          }
       configurations.all {
             resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$project.googlePlayServicesVersion"
           }
    }
```

If same issue coming then use

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

FYI Read [**`Android plugin for Gradle HTTP proxy settings`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#gradle-plugin)

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.company.com
        systemProp.http.proxyPort=443
        systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
        systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
        systemProp.http.auth.ntlm.domain=domain
    }
```

Comment: The Issue was with the internet connection, you can add instructions for adding a proxy to tns to your answer.

Comment: please update your answer to include the information that this might be due to network issues and explain that one can add a proxy with  `tns proxy set`